# How to implement Siril's MTF algorithm in GIMP plugin

Tags: plugins, gimp

I would like to implement Siril's Midtones Function Transfer algorithm in a GIMP plugin. Ideally, it would get 2 sliders (black level, midtones value) and a preview.

But I can't find a non-obsolete tutorial/example to implement a pixel operation with minimum GUI (sliders, preview...). Do you have an idea where to start ? Maybe a up-to-date example of plugin with pixel by pixel operation ? or with widget like sliders ?

```
# Siril's algortihm :

MTF(x;m) = ((m-1)x)/((2m-1)x-m)

# x : pixel value (float)
# m : midtones values float[0, 1]
```

https://free-astro.org/siril_doc-en/#Histograms

https://free-astro.org/index.php?title=Siril:Processing_tutorial

Siril is a great free software to process astrophotography, but it lacks some tools like layers, selection...

Answer (score 1):

For a full-capability plugin written in C the best place is Gimp's own source. Some filters are still defined as plugins in Gimp. See [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/tree/gimp-2-10/plug-ins).

Otherwise you can do a quick proof-of-concept in Python, with an auto-generated dialog for the two sliders (but no preview). The python interface defines "pixel regions" that map a python list directly over the Gimp data.
You can even [use Numpy](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-python-and-numpy).

For a Python POC:

- Official Gimp-python doc is [here](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/).
- Numpy link has an example script.
- Large set of example scripts [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).
- An example of all the UI widgets [here](http://www.dutchgimpers.nl/oud/index.php?n=ScriptFu.PythonRegister)
- Some hints about debugging your stuff [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Let's start with a proof of concept in python. Is there an API documentation/reference to know how to write a python interface ?

Comment: See augmented answer